# What are these called in Xcode - FIXME, TODO, ??? & !!!?

Tags: ios, xcode

I just learnt about these things - FIXME, TODO, ??? & !!!, in Xcode.
One blog referred to them as 'code markers' and one article as 'pragma marks'.

What is the correct term for them?

Answer (score 0):

This are the tags used to identify and navigate to the perticular files and methods.

For more details got to this link.

[Xcode FIXME and TODO](http://macdevelopertips.com/xcode/xcode-fixme-and-todo.html)

Comment: I know that but what do you call them?
Just 'tags' or is there a term?